# Spring Boot Application java -jar --property override not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've written a Spring Boot Application. I'm running the jar, while running the jar I'm overriding the property file keys for e.g: `java -jar example.jar --spring.profiles.active=test`, but the key is not overriding. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: What does your application's main method look like? Have you passed its args array into the call to `SpringApplication.run`?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I haven't passed the args to run method.

Comment: That's the problem, then. Update your main method so it passes in the args and it should work.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson thanks, that solved it.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson how to mark this as solved?

Comment: I've posted my comment as an answer along with an example main method. Feel free to accept it if you'd like your question to appear as having been answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For command line arguments to override properties, you need to pass the arguments from your application's main method into `SpringApplication.run`.

Your main method should look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(YourApplication.class, args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but I had all the configuration correctly and still wasn't working. It even worked in the past. So, eventually the solution to make it work again was a simple clean + package of the project.